# Function colored syntax highlighting for computed function names

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I'm using Visual Studio Code for a Vue + Vuex project. Like many others I use constants for action and mutation names, like below:

```
[MUTATION_NAME](args) {}
```

However the color of computed function names are not the color of regular function names as you can see in the picture:

[image: Example of computed vs regular function name]

This might be a dumb question, but is there a way to target and override the color for computed function names specifically?

Comment: what does command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` say about the difference of these tokens?

Comment: Cool, that's a neat feature. Semantic token type using square brackets is "variable" and without just "member". Square brackets don't have one but TextMate treats them as "meta.brace.square".

Comment: you can customize your theme based on the TextMate classes https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure you are right! Sadly, I don't really have time to learn it. :)